# Get column B from A mentioned below using text manipulation

Tags: r

```
   A                                                     B
   paytm?r=498472&ck-source=wsas-asfdww             498472
   paytm-clothing/r=498473&ck-source=wsas-sdfasd     498473
   paytm-cloths&r=4984&ck-source=wsas-sdfd            4984
```

need to return the numbers after ?r= , /r=  or &r= 
which can be four to six digits and following any of the pattern mentioned above .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr`.  We match the pattern of numbers that follow a `=` and extract it.

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(df1$A, "(?<=\\=)\\d+"))
#[1] 498472 498473   4984
```

If this needs to be specific (as mentioned in the post), we can match the numbers that follow either `?r=` `/r=` or `&r=`

```
 as.numeric(str_extract(df1$A, "(?<=(\\?|\\/|\\&)r\\=)\\d+"))
 #[1] 498472 498473   4984
```

---

Or use `sub` with capture groups.

```
 as.numeric(sub('.*(\\?|\\/|\\&)r\\=(\\d+).*', '\\2', df1$A))
 #[1] 498472 498473   4984
```